# Open the same PDF multiple times

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader

Is it possible to open the same PDF multiple times with Adobe Reader?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In acrobat reader 9 - To open the same document in a new tab in the same window, right click the tab, and choose **Duplicate Tab** then **detach tab** ( it will open in another window )

Comment: can't find this in adobe reader :/

Comment: try pressing Ctrl + T to open a new tab

Comment: i have chagned my answer this is works for me ;)

Comment: In Adobe Reader 9.3, there were no tabs, and I couldn't create one.

Comment: Solution below by @serhio worked for non-9.x version

Answer (score 39):

In **Adobe Reader XI** and **Adobe Acrobat Reader DC**

- Open your document;
- Go to the `Window` => `New Window`.

Now the first window should be duplicated.

Comment: Worked for me in Adobe Reader 9.3.

Answer (score 19):

Slight addition to serhio's answer.

In ***Acrobat Reader DC*** (released in 2015)

- Open your document;
- Go to the `Window` => `New Window`;
- Drag and drop the tab of the new window on to the tab bar of the old one.

Then you have two tabs for the same PDF file.

I think it's a great omission on the part of Adobe not to include a "Duplicate Tab" feature.